# Add custom header when create new remote database with pouchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm testing to send custom headers when creating a remote database with PouchDB. The fact is that according to the documentation the way to proceed is as follows (https://pouchdb.com/api.html):

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://example.com/dbname', {
  fetch: function (url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('X-Some-Special-Header', 'foo');
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
  }
});
```

My code is almost copied and pasted

```
const db = new PouchDB(this.server, {
  fetch(url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('xx-custom-xx', this.text);
    opts.credentials = 'include';
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
  }
});
```

When I try to launch it I get two errors:

- Error1: "export 'fetch' (imported as 'PouchDB') was not found in 'pouchdb' (possible exports: default)" This error is being given by the line"return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts); "
- Error2: "set does not exist on type headersinit"

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: In the second code section, `fetch(url, opts) {` should be `fetch: function(url,opts) {`, no?

Comment: @RamblinRose both works the same way

Comment: Maybe try `opts.headers['xx-custom-xx'] = this.text` instead. But I am just guessing here. You should probably debug the `opts` object using `console.log('opts', opts)` to see what kind of object it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it.. the problem are two.

First, I was importing Pouch like this

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

I have notice in other project I imported it by

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

In my new project with import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'; didn't work because I didn't set "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true flag in tsconfig

AllowSyntheticDefaultImports flag is specified in doc but It does't work (no for me) with import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';